# Batch extract a substring

Tags: batch-file

I want to format a path in batch, for example this:

```
C:\key\aa\bb\cc\key\rem.txt
```

I want to obtain:

```
C:\key\aa\bb\cc\key
```

I have tried:

```
1. set path=C:\key\aa\bb\cc\key\rem.txt
2. set KEY=key
3. FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ("*\*\!KEY!") do SET delete=!path:%%a=!
4. FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ("\!KEY!!delete!") do SET pts=!path:%%a=!
```

It doesn't work if I let **!KEY! at line 3.
The key before C:\ is my problem if I don't have this word then this works:

```
1. set path=C:\**dd**\aa\bb\cc\key\rem.txt
2. set KEY=key
3. FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ("*!KEY!") do SET delete=!path:%%a=!
4. FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ("\!KEY!!delete!") do SET pts=!path:%%a=!
```

How can I obtain the path I want ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you simply do:

```
set "target=C:\key\aa\bb\cc\key\rem.txt"
set "format="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%target%") do (set format="%%~dpa")
Echo %format%
```

And that would retrieve the direcotry path.

Mona.